# ASP Upload larger Files -150 mb

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to upload Files in my ASP-App. And it works with 137mb .csv-Files. But now I want to upload a 149mb File and it gives me an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET...

My Webconfig:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="300000000" executionTimeout="800000" />
```

and:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/> 
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Why the sql tag?

Comment: Actually, everything seems OK. Did you do `iisreset` after changing the web.config?

Comment: I tried but still ERR_Connection...

Comment: @ASP_Soldier After how many seconds are you getting the error?

Comment: About 1 Minute after and after ca. 70% Upload

Comment: First I had a Folder "Files" where I put the CSV but now the system deletes it. I don't know why... So I stored it in the bin Folder but it seems that the system (inetpub) also deletes the files after a certain time. Maybe that the reason why it results in an error. Maybe the file is deleted before it's completly uplaoded?